# using method on a manager pylint thinks class is an undefined variable

Tags: django

I have a class called Passengers in my models.py

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
first = models.CharField(max_length=64)
last = models.CharField(max_length=64)
flights = models.ManyToManyField(Flight, blank=True, related_name="passengers")

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

In views.py I'm defining this view where I am finding the passenger id from the submitted form data and at the same time finding the passenger based on the id using .objects.get.

```
def book(request, flight_id):
if request.method == "POST":
    flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
    passenger.flights.add(flight)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight", args=(flight.id)))
```

The problem is that Passenger is not recognised as a class but rather as an undefined variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MaSX.png)

Comment: Did you forget to import your `Passenger` model in your view ? Something like `from .models import Passenger` at the beginning of your file `views.py`

Comment: Hi @Benbb96, yes I did indeed. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome ! I'll just add an answer so you can accept it and close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines at the beginning of your `views.py` :

```
from .models import Passenger
```